# Yii validation rule not working

Tags: yii, php

I created a file uploaded validation rule without a table in my database, so what I did is I just extended it using CFormModel.

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
public function actionMaterials($pid)
{
    $projectMaterialFile = new ProjectMaterialFile;
    $this->render('project_materials',array(
        'projectMaterialFile'=>$projectMaterialFile,
    ));
}
```

**VIEW (Project Material)**

```
<div id="exportMaterialContent">
    <h4 style="text-align:left;">Export Material Document</h4>
    <?php echo CHtml::form($this->createUrl("project/export"),'post',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeHiddenField( $projectMaterialFile,'idProject',array('value'=>$projectModel->idProject) ); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($projectMaterialFile, 'document'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton("Export"); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
</div>
```

**Controller - Export(After the form from the view has been submitted)**

```
public function actionExport()
{
    $model = new ProjectMaterialFile;
    $model->attributes = $_POST['ProjectMaterialFile'];
    if( $model->validate() ) {
        $model->document = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'document');
        $model->document->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')."/material_document/".$model->document->name);
        echo "correct";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid!";
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class ProjectMaterialFile extends CFormModel
{
    public $document;
    public $idProject;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('document','file','types'=>'csv'),
            array('document', 'required'),
        );
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'document' => 'Project Material Document',
            'idProject' => 'Project ID',
        );
    }
}
```

So what I did here is that it always run to the else of my controller `actionExport()`
Even if I try to `echo $model->validate();`, it does not print anything that's why it always go to the else statement.

Your help would be greatly appreciated and of course, rewarded!

Thanks! :)

Comment: can you paste print_r  of $model->attributes ?

Comment: Weird but this is the output: Array ( [document] => [idProject] => )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change validation rules in your model as below

```
public function rules()
{
   return array(
      array('document','file','types'=>'csv'),
      array('document', 'required'),
      array('document', 'length', 'max'=>200),
      array('idProject', 'length', 'max'=>200),
      array('document, idProject', 'safe'),
      );
}
```

Now change your controller part as below

```
$model = new ProjectMaterialFile;
$model->attributes = $_POST['ProjectMaterialFile'];
$model->document = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'document');

if( $model->validate() )
{
   $model->document->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')
                ."/material_document/".$model->document->name);
    echo "Correct";
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid!";
}
```

Example Link: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/